# Why onPushMessageReceived() is not called in Geoloqi API in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, push-notification, android-c2dm, geofencing

In my android app i am using Latest Geoloqi API to implement Geofence concept.when user entered into some region he has notify, for that purpose i am using Push Notifications.in GeoReceiver class three callback methods are calling but not onPushMessageReceived().please help me how to do it?
I am creating trigger with current location is it required to enter into region manually or since i am already in the location its not calling?
Note:I ve given required credentials in assets/geoloqi.properties file.when app is launched in logcat "Successfully registered for the C2DM service" msg also displayed.my code:

GeoloqiExampleActivity.java

```
public class GeoloqiExampleActivity extends Activity{
    String TAG = "Geoloqi Example";

     private LQService mService;
     private boolean mBound;
     GeoReceiver geoReceiver = new GeoReceiver();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LQService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // Bind to the tracking service so we can call public methods on it
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LQService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, 0);

        // Wire up the sample location receiver
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(GeoReceiver.ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(GeoReceiver.ACTION_TRACKER_PROFILE_CHANGED);
        filter.addAction(GeoReceiver.ACTION_LOCATION_UPLOADED);
        filter.addAction(GeoReceiver.ACTION_PUSH_MESSAGE_RECEIVED);
        registerReceiver(geoReceiver, filter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // Unbind from LQService
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
        // Unregister our location receiver
        unregisterReceiver(geoReceiver);
    }
    public void sendRequest() {

         // Performing a Trigger POST request
        if (mService != null) {
            LQSession session = mService.getSession();
            LQTracker tracker = mService.getTracker();
            tracker.setSession(session);
            // Build your request
            JSONObject trigger = new JSONObject();
            try {
                trigger.put("text", "Popcornapps");
                trigger.put("type", "message");
                trigger.put("latitude", 17.42557068);
                trigger.put("longitude",  78.42022822);
                trigger.put("radius", 500);
                trigger.put("place_name", "Banjara Hills");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
               Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            // Send the request
            session.runPostRequest("trigger/create", trigger, new OnRunApiRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LQSession session, HttpResponse response) {

                    Toast.makeText(GeoloqiExampleActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
                        String sResponse;
                        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            s = s.append(sResponse);
                        }
                    String result = s.toString().trim();
                    Log.d("On success Result", result);

                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(LQSession session, LQException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(GeoloqiExampleActivity.this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete(LQSession session, HttpResponse response, StatusLine status) {
                    Toast.makeText(GeoloqiExampleActivity.this, "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "service null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

     /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            try {
                // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance.
                LQBinder binder = (LQBinder) service;
                mService = binder.getService();
                mBound = true;
                sendRequest();//Sending API Request
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

GeoReceiver.java

```
public class GeoReceiver extends LQBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Context arg0, Location arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Loc Changed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPushMessageReceived(Context context, Bundle data) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Push Msg Received ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationUploaded(Context arg0, int arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "Location Uploaded ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrackerProfileChanged(Context arg0, LQTrackerProfile oldp,
            LQTrackerProfile newp) {
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "onTrackerProfileChanged ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pop.geoloqi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.pop.geoloqi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.pop.geoloqi.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

         <activity
            android:name=".GeoloqiExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.geoloqi.android.sdk.service.LQService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".GeoReceiver"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.geoloqi.android.sdk.action.LOCATION_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.geoloqi.android.sdk.receiver.LQDeviceMessagingReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.pop.geoloqi" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: If you are using wifi make sure it is not firewalled. simple way to check is to see gtalk is able to sign you in or not. And please make sure you are using android 2.2+ device with market app installed and one gmail id properly configured.

Comment: @KKD I ve checked wifi is not firewalled.Device is Android 3.1 market app installed with one gmail id.

Comment: Are you able to log in to gtalk? Is your server getting STATUS_OK message after you contact c2dm server?

Comment: yes i am able to login gtalk..directly i m not communicating to c2dm its geologi api..please visit the following link once. https://developers.geoloqi.com/android/push-notifications

Comment: Then I am afraid I can't provide any help I have never used geoloqi. It is wonderful though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in earlier versions of the Geoloqi Android SDK. If you update to the [latest version](https://github.com/geoloqi/Geoloqi-Android-SDK) this problem should be resolved.